# How do you see that higher genus surfaces are not homogeneous?

Tags: riemann-surfaces, dg.differential-geometry

I am trying to get some intuition about why the torus and the sphere are the only surfaces which can be realised as homogeneous spaces.  On the one hand, I know this is true because there is the result that homogeneous spaces must have non-negative Euler characteristic:

[A Structure Theorem for Homogeneous Spaces, Mostow, G, Geometriae Dedicata, (114) 2005, 87-102](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10711-004-1675-9)

However, on the other hand, a higher genus surface can be realised as a quotient of hyperbolic space by a group of isometries.  The latter would seem (in my head) to give rise to a hyperbolic surface where the points look the same; all of the points have the same curvature, for instance.

My question is then: How do you distinguish the points of such a hyperbolic surface?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_point

Comment: I think your intuition is right when you say that "the points look the same" in the sense that the surface is not (globally) homogeneous 
but it is certainly locally homogeneous as a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: but the Weierstrass points are "special" with respect to the complex structure of the curve (that is, since we are in complex dimention $1$, for the metric or rather its conformal class). On the other hand, the group of diffeomorphisms acts transitively on any smooth manifold. Can the presence of Weierstrass points rule out the possibility that the surface is differentiably of the form $G/H$ for some *real* Lie groups $G$ and $H$?

Comment: After reading two answers I'm led to ask: in the question, is "homogeneus space" intended to include a Riemannian metric? There is also the purely differentiable notion of homogeneus space (as, e.g., per  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_space ). Maybe there is also a reasonably easy proof just in the differentiable setting...

Comment: @Claudio: "I think your intuition is right when you say that "the points look the same" in the sense that the surface is not (globally) homogeneous but it is certainly locally homogeneous as a Riemannian manifold."  As I am sure you realize, that is true for every Riemannian manifold.  Perhaps the OP should make his question more precise: obviously "homogeneous" in the sense of admitting a transitive action of a (finite dimensional) real Lie group is very different from "the points look the same" in the sense that sufficiently small charts are isomorphic.  So what does the OP want?

Comment: @Jason: Riemannian manifolds in general do *not* look the same locally!

Comment: The group of diffeomorphisms   of a  smooth connected manifold acts transitively on that manifold. In that sense, any smooth connected  manifold is homogeneous. On the other hand, if a  *compact* group $G$ acts  transitively on   a  smooth manifold, then  by averaging one can produce a Riemann metric on that manifold  which is  $G$-invariant.


Comment: My last comment was <B>completely</B> wrong!  I was misreading "Riemannian manifold" as "differentiable manifold".  Now I understand Claudio's comment.

Comment: FYI, the unit tangent bundle to a Riemann surface is homogeneous, since $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ acts transitively on it (with non-compact stabilizers, so not preserving a metric). This fact is important in understanding the spectrum of the Laplacian, and carries over to other locally homogeneous spaces. 

Comment: @Agol: "and carries over to other locally homogeneous spaces": I only understand it in rank one symmetric spaces, when the action of $K$ on the unit sphere of the tangent space of the base-point of $G/K$ is transitive: here the locally homogeneous space is $\Gamma\backslash G/K$, so under this transitivity assumption the unit tangent space is the left quotient $\Gamma\backslash G$. 

Comment: Thanks for the useful replies everyone.  The key pointers for me were the terms "geodesics" and "Weierstrass points".  I've now stitched together much better intuition from what people have said.

Comment: Mostow's theorem is about transitive smooth actions of Lie groups. Proving non-existence of such an action is much harder than proving non-existence of a transitive isometric action (which is what all three answers are doing).

Answer (score 10):

There is   a classical theorem of Hurwitz  which states that the group of biholomorphisms of a Riemann surface of genus $g>1$ contains at most $84(g-1)$ elements. Such a Riemann surface   cannot be a homogeneous space because the (orientation preserving) isometries are conformal maps and thus they are  also  biholomorphic maps.

The proof is of Hurwitz' theorem is based on the concept of *Weierstrass point*. There  are at least $2g+2$ such points on any Riemann surface of genus $g>1$, but  their number is bounded  from above by  a universal function of $g$. The set of such points is a biholomorphism invariant.   The clincher is that a biholomorphic map of a Riemann surface cannot have too many fixed points. For more details see  Eric Reyssat's *Quelques Aspects des Surfaces de Riemann*, Birkhauser or  Rick Miranda's  *Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces*,  Amer. Math. Soc.

Answer (score 8):

Another way to see it is this: there is a unique geodesic in each nontrivial homotopy class because the surface is hyperbolic so that energy is a convex function on loops. If the surface were homogeneous (i.e. admitted a transitive Lie group action (EDIT: by isometries)) then you would be able to move geodesics around to fill out the space. You get distinguished points this way as intersections between geodesics. The universal cover is homogeneous, of course, but there is no nontrivial homotopy class.

EDIT: As the OP asked about hyperbolic surfaces, I interpreted homogeneous space to mean Riemannian homogeneous space/Klein geometry. I interpreted the question to be "Given that the geometry is locally homogeneous, how can we distinguish special points?". You have to use a global tool.

Answer (score 3):

One way to distinguish points of a hyperbolic surface $S$ is to show that the local geometry of the Voronoi graph of a point $p$ is changed when $p$ is perturbed. The Voronoi graph is a connected 1-complex consisting of the locus of points on $S$ for which there are two or more shortest paths to $p$; its complement is an open 2-cell which is the locus of points for which there is a unique shortest path to $p$. Equivalently, it is the projection to $S$ of the [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) for the full pre-image of $p$ under a locally isometric universal covering map $\mathbb{H}^2 \mapsto S$. You need a nontrivial fundamental group to get a nonempty Voronoi graph, and a noncyclic fundamental group to get a Voronoi graph more complicated than a bi-infinite geodesic and therefore possessing at least one 0-cell (point of valence three or more).

Suppose that $x$ is a certain 0-cell of the Voronoi graph, a point at which there are three or more shortest paths to $p$. If $x$ has valence three, which is the "generic" situation, then $p$ can be perturbed so that the three angles of the 1-cells incident to $x$ are changed; this can be verified by some simple hyperbolic trigonometry calculations. If $x$ has valence four or more, then $p$ can be perturbed to change the local topology of the Voronoi graph near $x$, breaking $x$ into two or more vertices of smaller valence.

By the way, with regard to the two topological types of closed Euclidean surfaces, while the torus is always homogeneous in any Euclidean metric, the Klein bottle is never homogeneous, because an orientation reversing simple closed geodesic is unique in its homotopy class.

---

Further remarks: I addressed Igor's first question in my comment below. To address his second question, the answer I am offering to the OP's question is that points $p \in S$ can be locally distinguished by the local geometry of their Voronoi graph $V(p)$. By this I mean two things: (1) for each $p,q \in S$, there exists an isometry of $S$ taking $p$ to $q$ if and only if $V(p)$ is locally isometric to $V(q)$; (2) for $q$ near $p$ there does not exist a local isometry between $V(p)$ and $V(q)$.

To fill this in somewhat: the edges of $V(p)$ are geodesic arcs, and the local geometry of $V(p)$ is determined by the topological type of its embedding into its regular neighborhood $Nhd(V(p))$, by the lengths of its edges, and by the angles around its vertices. To prove the ``if'' direction of (1), once the local isometry type of $V(p)$ is determined, there is a unique way to fill in $Nhd(V(p)) - V(p)$ by an open hyperbolic disc. The cheapest proof of (2) is to use (1) together with the fact that the isometry group of $S$ acts discretely on $S$, which of course requires already knowing the latter fact, using a proof that depends for example on facts about geodesics explained in the other answers.

As alluded to, there is a much more expensive proof of (2) which uses hyperbolic trigonometry, which under special assumptions goes like this. Assume first that vertices of $V(p)$ have valence 3. Cut $S$ open along $V(p)$ to get a convex hyperbolic polygon containing $p$. Assume further that there is a perpendicular geodesic from $p$ to each side of this polygon (not true in general). Use those perpendiculars, and the geodesics from $p$ to the vertices, to cut the polygon into hyperbolic right triangles. Write down equations relating the shapes of these right triangles to the local geometry of the Voronoi graph. Use these equations to prove (with much agony) that as $p$ is perturbed the local geometry of the Voronoi graph changes.

Comment: Why does this argument not work for the torus?

Comment: Because the deck transformation group of the torus is a subgroup of the translation group. So when you perturb $p$, and lift to the total orbit of $p$, all of the points in that orbit are perturbed by adding the same little vector, and so the entire Voronoi diagram is perturbed by adding the same little vector, and the angles are unaffected.

Comment: I guess this is really just walking through the proof that a torus is homogeneous.

Comment: I think we all agree that the torus is homogeneous, my question was: what about your argument depends on strictly negative curvature?

Comment: @Lee: Your suggestion sounds way too painful. Even proving that generically Voronoi tiling has 3-valent graph is not at all easy, it was done in 2007 by Diaz and Ushijima (their proof could be simplified though). An easier argument is to consider not just Voronoi tiling of the hyperbolic plane associated with the given orbit, but the entire collection of bisectors of points in the orbit. Then you can see how angles change already in the case of cyclic group (angle/distance between bisectors depends on distance from the point to the axis). @Igor: This is where I would use hyperbolicity. 

Comment: @Misha: I feel your pain, having worked on this approach for a while when a fresh postdoc. But I always retained a curiosity about a couple of questions: If one decomposes $S$ into regions for which the Voronoi graphs are isotopic, what does this decomposition look like? If one takes the isotopy class of this labelled decomposition of $S$ (with each region labelled by the associated isotopy class of subgraphs), how does this decomposition vary as $S$ moves around moduli space? 