# classification of homogenous complex manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a complex manifold (doesn't assume it's Kahler), and it's holomorhpic automorphism group is transitive.  My question is that is there any classification of those manifolds ?

Comment: At least for Riemann surfaces, [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/104104/21564) seems helpful.

Comment: I assume you want your manifolds to be *compact*, otherwise it is hopeless. Then you may be interested by the papers of D. Guan, see [here](http://www.math.ucr.edu/~zguan/bib.html). Under some mild extra hypotheses, such manifold is a product of a projective one (those are well-understood) and a complex solvmanifold. Note however that there is no hope to completely classify the latter, they are just too many.